# Написать ряд Фибоначчи через лямбду не принимающую аргументов

Tags: c++, lambda

Создайте переменную с названием fib, которая является лямбдой. Каждый вызов этой переменной выводид по очередности элементы ряда Фибоначчи начиная от 0.
Можно написать в пару строчек, используя std::exchange.
Пример кода:

```
auto fib = ...;
cout << fib;
cout << fib;
cout << fib;
cout << fib;
```

Вывести должно: 0 1 1 2 
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Вы сформулируйте так, как задание задано вам. Не своими словами, а точно.

Answer (score 1):

Так можно сделать, почти так как Вы хотите. (если что - код грязный, его нужно чуточку улучшить)

```cpp
int main() {
auto fib = []() -> int {
    static int i = 0;
    static int p1 = 0;
    static int p2 = 0;
    i++;
    if (i == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (i == 2) {
        p1 = 1;
        p2 = 0;
        return 1;
    } else {
        int n = p1+p2;
        p2 = p1;
        p1 = n;
        return n;
    }
};

std::cout << fib();
std::cout << fib();
std::cout << fib();
std::cout << fib();
std::cout << fib();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Задание сделать именно через лямбду. 
Получилось что-то такое:

```
int i = 0;
int i1= 1;
int res  = 0;
auto fibonacci = [&i,&i1,&res](){
    i=i1;
    i1=res;
    return std::exchange(res,i + i1);
};
        std::cout << fibonacci() << ' '
        << fibonacci() << ' '
        << fibonacci() << ' '
        << fibonacci() << ' '
        << fibonacci();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, переменных нужно только две, захватывать что-то снаружи или городить статики также не требуется:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto fib
    {
        [cur{0}, next{1}] (void) mutable
        {
            auto const prev{cur};
            cur = next;
            next = prev + cur;
            return prev;
        } 
    };
    for (auto count{10}; 0 < count; --count)
    {
        ::std::cout << fib() << ::std::endl;
    }
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/BXNGok)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    auto fib = [f1 = 0u, f2 = 1u]() mutable { 
        return std::exchange(f1, std::exchange(f2, f2 + f1)); 
    };    


    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "fib " << i << " = " << fib() << "\n";
    }
}
```